# Unable to set default value for array in use state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I want to set default value to my state, but it's getting undefined. But if I refresh my page values get assigned to categoryIds.

```
  const si = [...searchParams.getAll("cat")];
  console.log("si", si);

  let sinew = [];
  si.forEach((c) => {
    sinew.push(catmap2.get(c));
  });
  console.log("sinew", sinew);  //print sinew correctly with ids

 

  const [categoryIds, setCategoryIds] = useState(si.length==0? [] : sinew);

  console.log("catids", categoryIds);   //It gives array of same size as sinew but with undefined values
```

I have also tried to set it using useEffect but got same issue.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(sinew);  //prints correctlty
    setCategoryIds(sinew);  // but CategoryIds still have undefined values
  }, []);
```

[image: Output]

Comment: so `catmap2.get(c)` returns undefined. fix it

Comment: @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOV not it's getting correct value. When I print console.log("sinew", sinew); . It prints correct array values which got from catmap2.get(c).

Comment: @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOV how can you tell? The definition is not even in the above

Comment: Care to share the definition of `catmap2.get(c)`? Does it run [asynchronously](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Introducing#:~:text=Asynchronous%20programming%20is%20a%20technique,is%20presented%20with%20the%20result.)? If it does, the page might have rendered before that code reaches completion, leading to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to set the initial state of `categoryIds` with the value of `sinew`. However, `sinew` is a derived value from `si` which is also derived from `searchParams.getAll("cat")`. If `searchParams.getAll("cat")` is asynchronous or depends on some other state or props, then `sinew` and `categoryIds` might not be set correctly during the first render.

You said you try to use the `useEffect` hook to update the state when the `sinew` value changes. However, you should ensure that `sinew` is not changing during the component's lifecycle, otherwise, it will cause an infinite loop.

Then, How?

The below is the sample execution that I can give to help you.

```
const [categoryIds, setCategoryIds] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
 const si = [...searchParams.getAll("cat")];
 let sinew = [];
 si.forEach((c) => {
   sinew.push(catmap2.get(c));
 });
 setCategoryIds(sinew);
}, [searchParams]);
```

Here, the `useEffect` will run every time `searchParams` changes, and it will update `categoryIds` with the new `sinew` value.

However, if `searchParams.getAll("cat")` is synchronous and you're sure that `sinew` is not changing during the component's lifecycle, you should check if `catmap2.get(c)` is returning `undefined` for some `c` in `si`. This could be the reason why you're seeing undefined values in `categoryIds`.

Comment: [searchParams] was changing on every render. caused an infinite loop. I changed it to [catmap2]. Remaing worked fine thanks.